# remove line items by property, not values, in an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an object like this:

```
var obj = [
 {
        item1: 'test',
    item2: 'something',
    item3: 'REMOVE THIS',
    item4: 'REMOVE THIS',
    item5: 'REMOVE THIS',
 },
 {
        item1: 'test',
    item2: 'something',
    item3: 'REMOVE THIS',
    item4: 'REMOVE THIS',
    item5: 'REMOVE THIS',
 },
 {
        item1: 'test',
    item2: 'something',
    item3: 'REMOVE THIS',
    item4: 'REMOVE THIS',
    item5: 'REMOVE THIS',
 }
]
```

I want `obj` to now represent this:

```
var obj = [
 {
        item1: 'test',
    item2: 'something',
 },
 {
        item1: 'test',
    item2: 'something',
 },
 {
        item1: 'test',
    item2: 'something',
 }
]
```

I found a lot of answers about object manipulation and using keys etc

[JavaScript: filter() for Objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5072136/javascript-filter-for-objects)

[How to filter an object of objects efficiently?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48842043/how-to-filter-an-object-of-objects-efficiently)

[How to filter an object with its values in ES6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44025984/how-to-filter-an-object-with-its-values-in-es6)

The problem with these answers is

1. its a specific object format, and they don't cover how to do multiple objects
2. It removes objects completely, not value and keys/line items

The closest I have it is this:

```js
var obj = [
 {
        item1: 'test',
    item2: 'something',
    item3: 'REMOVE THIS',
    item4: 'REMOVE THIS',
    item5: 'REMOVE THIS',
 },
 {
        item1: 'test',
    item2: 'something',
    item3: 'REMOVE THIS',
    item4: 'REMOVE THIS',
    item5: 'REMOVE THIS',
 },
 {
        item1: 'test',
    item2: 'something',
    item3: 'REMOVE THIS',
    item4: 'REMOVE THIS',
    item5: 'REMOVE THIS',
 }
]

var newObj = [];

obj.forEach(function(el){
    newObj.push(el.item1);
  newObj.push(el.item2);
})

console.log(newObj)
```

Obviously this isn't quite it because I need to push the full object not just the key values.

I'm trying something like this [How to filter an object with its values in ES6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44025984/how-to-filter-an-object-with-its-values-in-es6) but this answer won't work because it's doing by value and not by key(?)

```js
var obj = [
 {
        item1: 'test',
    item2: 'something',
    item3: 'REMOVE THIS',
    item4: 'REMOVE THIS',
    item5: 'REMOVE THIS',
 },
 {
        item1: 'test',
    item2: 'something',
    item3: 'REMOVE THIS',
    item4: 'REMOVE THIS',
    item5: 'REMOVE THIS',
 },
 {
        item1: 'test',
    item2: 'something',
    item3: 'REMOVE THIS',
    item4: 'REMOVE THIS',
    item5: 'REMOVE THIS',
 }
]

var acceptedProps = ['item1', 'item2'];

var newObj = Object.keys(obj).reduce(function(r, e) {
  if (acceptedProps.includes(obj[e])) r[e] = obj[e]
  return r;
}, {})

console.log(newObj)
```

It's just giving me an empty array. I tried flipping some stuff around as well

```js
var obj = [
 {
        item1: 'test',
    item2: 'something',
    item3: 'REMOVE THIS',
    item4: 'REMOVE THIS',
    item5: 'REMOVE THIS',
 },
 {
        item1: 'test',
    item2: 'something',
    item3: 'REMOVE THIS',
    item4: 'REMOVE THIS',
    item5: 'REMOVE THIS',
 },
 {
        item1: 'test',
    item2: 'something',
    item3: 'REMOVE THIS',
    item4: 'REMOVE THIS',
    item5: 'REMOVE THIS',
 }
]

var acceptedProps = ['item1', 'item2'];

var newObj = Object.keys(obj).reduce(function(r, e) {
  if (acceptedProps.includes(obj[r])) r[e] = obj[r]
  return r;
}, {})

console.log(newObj)
```

idk what `r` and `e` means in this function?

How do you filter objects by property and not value, for an array of multiple objects?

**EDIT** - okay I just found this answer:

[Remove array element based on object property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15287865/remove-array-element-based-on-object-property)

```js
var obj = [
 {
        item1: 'test',
    item2: 'something',
    item3: 'REMOVE THIS',
    item4: 'REMOVE THIS',
    item5: 'REMOVE THIS',
 },
 {
        item1: 'test',
    item2: 'something',
    item3: 'REMOVE THIS',
    item4: 'REMOVE THIS',
    item5: 'REMOVE THIS',
 },
 {
        item1: 'test',
    item2: 'something',
    item3: 'REMOVE THIS',
    item4: 'REMOVE THIS',
    item5: 'REMOVE THIS',
 }
]

var newObj = obj.filter(function( obj ) {
    return obj.field !== 'item3';
});

console.log(newObj)
```

So now...I have to somehow change it to a lop(?) and update each object without the line item...

```js
var obj = [
 {
        item1: 'test',
    item2: 'something',
    item3: 'REMOVE THIS',
    item4: 'REMOVE THIS',
    item5: 'REMOVE THIS',
 },
 {
        item1: 'test',
    item2: 'something',
    item3: 'REMOVE THIS',
    item4: 'REMOVE THIS',
    item5: 'REMOVE THIS',
 },
 {
        item1: 'test',
    item2: 'something',
    item3: 'REMOVE THIS',
    item4: 'REMOVE THIS',
    item5: 'REMOVE THIS',
 }
]

var obj = [
 {
        item1: 'test',
    item2: 'something',
    item3: 'REMOVE THIS',
    item4: 'REMOVE THIS',
    item5: 'REMOVE THIS',
 },
 {
        item1: 'test',
    item2: 'something',
    item3: 'REMOVE THIS',
    item4: 'REMOVE THIS',
    item5: 'REMOVE THIS',
 },
 {
        item1: 'test',
    item2: 'something',
    item3: 'REMOVE THIS',
    item4: 'REMOVE THIS',
    item5: 'REMOVE THIS',
 }
]

var newObj = obj.forEach(function(el) {
  el.filter(function( el ) {
    return el.field !== 'item3';
  });
})

console.log(newObj)
```

but I get:

`el.filter is not a function` ...

How do I do this? what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like that

```
obj.map((item) => {
  return {
    item1: item.item1,
    item2: item.item2,
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Array.map()` to iterate over the array items to create new array, `Object.entries()` to filter out the values of the objects that are the items of the array, and use `Object.fromEntries()` to build object back from the filtered entries.

```js
var obj = [{
    item1: 'test',
    item2: 'something',
    item3: 'REMOVE THIS',
    item4: 'REMOVE THIS',
    item5: 'REMOVE THIS',
  },
  {
    item1: 'test',
    item2: 'something',
    item3: 'REMOVE THIS',
    item4: 'REMOVE THIS',
    item5: 'REMOVE THIS',
  },
  {
    item1: 'test',
    item2: 'something',
    item3: 'REMOVE THIS',
    item4: 'REMOVE THIS',
    item5: 'REMOVE THIS',
  }
];

var newObj = obj.map(item => Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(item)
  .filter(([key, value]) => value !== 'REMOVE THIS')
));

console.log(newObj);
```